# Is there any benefit to combos?

Tags: battle-for-bikini-bottom-rehydrated

When you destroy multiple boxes or enemies at once in *SpongeBob Squarepants: Battle for Bikini Bottom - Rehydrated*, text appears that says you got a combo. The more boxes you break the better the combo text. Does getting a combo have any benefit (like increasing how many shiny objects you get) or is it just for show?

[image]